# How sync sql server 2008-R2 (remopte server with local) using Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, remote-server

How can i sync sql server 2008-R2 (remopte server and local) using Microsoft Sync Framework?
there are tons of documentations about that framework, but i could n't find a step-by-step guide for synchronization.
i downloaded Sync Framework 2.1 SDK From [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23217)
just a framework and after installation there are some dlls in program files folder.
now what should i do and which **Tools** should i use?
where can i downlaod those tools?
i saw a tool (PUTTY.exe) in one of servers that i have access. what is this tool and is it in relationship with sync framework?
i have two databases(sql server 2008 - R2) : **A** in Local And **B** in a Web server.
both of these databases are the same and i just want to sync their data with a scheduled program.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation includes a walkthrough/tutorial, see:

[Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700)

this should work with SQL Server to SQL Sever as well and you should find the same in the documentation that gets installed with the SDK.

here's a sample using WCF:
[Database Sync:SQL Server and SQL Express N-Tier with WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208)